# check if entry is in list, no matter if it's uppercase or lowercase: python

Tags: python, string, list, methods

I am trying to check if an entry is in a list based on user input, no matter if the input is a combination of uppercase or lowercase letters. Say I have the TV show name 'Stranger Things' in my list. I want to print 'Stranger Things' from the list even if the user inputs 'st', 'St', 'ST', or 'sT'.

I think I should get input as .lower(), but does this mean I have to convert all string in my list using .lower()? If so, how can I go about doing this with a large amount of data in my list?

Answer (score 0):

You could either convert the list to all lowercase words, or you could do something like this:

```
shows = ['Stranger Things', 'The Office', 'Show 3', 'etc']
if word in map(str.lower, shows):
    {do something}
```

If you need to retain both the "proper" version (e.g. "Stranger Things") as well as the all lowercase version, you could make a dictionary and store the lowercase version as the key and the uppercase version as the value. This way you could see if the show is in the `shows` dictionary, and get the "proper" version. An example of this would be:

```
shows = {"stranger things": "Stranger Things", "the office": "The Office", "show 3": "Show 3"}
if word in shows.keys():
    print(shows[word])  # prints the proper version of the word
```

Comment: Your map function hould be reversed. The correct order of arguments is map(function, iterable)